# I can't generate a signed apk / abb file from my android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a completely working ( no errors ) android studio. and i tried running it on the emulator, which was successfully accomplished ,
[image: App Running Successfully On Emulator]

but when i try to generate a signed apk, the build throws 3 errors,

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\haamh\Downloads\only\Android-WebView-in-Kotlin-master\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-45:19: AAPT: error: resource mipmap/ic_launcher (aka com.onlywin.hhh:mipmap/ic_launcher) not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

[image: the build log]

But i have all those three folders/assets in my project and i have even tried replacing i.e deleteing the whole minimap directory and added everything again !

**I don't really know why the app runs on emulator with no errors and throws this meaningless error when i try to generate a signed apk.**

and i have no errors in my manifest file,
[image: no errors in androidmanifest file]

and i have all those three folders with image assets too !

[image]

Comment: There are some error in your Manifest file

Comment: Can you show the full structure of your `res` folder? Expand all folders and add take a screenshot

Comment: Go to project view and show res folder. Check if you have any debug/release folder in project.

Comment: i have edited as per your requests @sajidjuneja

Comment: Click the Android drop down you can see and change to project view and then share screenshot.

Comment: it's not showing in the project view, the minimap folder is empty in the project view?

Comment: @sajidjuneja it's still not showing even after i created a new asset in project view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in your manifest file studio not finding your app icon path

**Change app icon to drawable folder**

[image]

Comment: i have a image asset not a vector/ xml file and it's imported as a directory , do u want me to move those directories to drawable folder instead of minimap?

Comment: yes after moving to drawable problem will be solve

Comment: i can't move a directory to drawable folder

Comment: copy any one icon from mipmap and paste in drawer folder and use it